# Center a video vertically in mobile

Tags: html, css

This is my code. I'm trying to play the video automatically on devices with larger Widths and have a custom play button on lower width devices which doesn't support autoplay on videos with audio. It's working well on large width devices, but on mobile devices it is sticking to the top of screen. I want to center it to the screen. I have tried various methods but none helped. Please help
[This is how it is looking on mobile phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVNJu.jpg)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<center>
<div class="wrapper">
<video id="hey" class="video" autoplay playsinline>
<source src="http://e14aaeb709f7cde1ae68-a1d0a134a31b545b257b15f8a8ba5726.r70.cf3.rackcdn.com/projects/31432/1427815464209-bf74131a7528d0ea5ce8c0710f530bb5/1280x720.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
</div>
<div class="playpause"></div>
</div><center>
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px){
.video {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.wrapper{
   
    display:table;
    width:auto;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
.playpause {
    background-image:url("play.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0%;
    right:0%;
    top:0%;
    bottom:0%;
    margin:auto;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position: center;
}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1021px) and (max-width : 1600px){
.video {
object-fit: cover;   
width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}}

</style>
<script>
document.getElementById('hey').addEventListener('ended',function(){
         window.location.href = 'http://www.your-url.com';
 },false);
$('.video').parent().click(function () {
  if($(this).children(".video").get(0).paused){        $(this).children(".video").get(0).play();   $(this).children(".playpause").fadeOut();
    }else{       $(this).children(".video").get(0).pause();
  $(this).children(".playpause").fadeIn();
    }
});</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the only element in your page, do this:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Basically the content is not enough to cover the whole height of the screen, and the `body` element takes only the size of which the video is. So you have to explicitly make it so that `body` takes the entire screen height and then center the content inside it.